# LINUX - saltstack cmd.run in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, salt-stack

I know I can use sls to run commands from salt but I have a requirement to run certain commands via bash script. I need to store the result of the command into a variable.

When running the following on the shell of the salt server it works and I get a result

```
salt -t70 'server' cmd.run "cat /etc/shadow | grep user |cut -d: -f3"
```

But when I migrate the command to a variable inside a bash file in the salt server it doesn't.

**BASH.SH**

```
test = $(echo salt -t70 $server cmd.run "cat /etc/shadow | grep $user |cut -d\":\" -f3");
echo $test;
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
[root@saltserver ~]# sh bash.sh
bash.sh: line 13: test: too many arguments
```

What am I missing? What do I need to fix to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full content of your bash script? What is on line 13?

Comment: @mattias, no additional context is needed; there's enough here to diagnose this issue.

Comment: BTW -- http://shellcheck.net/ would have found this bug for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put spaces around your `=` in an assignment -- doing so makes the operation... well, no longer an assignment. That is to say:

Use

```
# assign result to a variable named test
test=$(echo salt -t70 $server cmd.run "cat /etc/shadow | grep $user |cut -d\":\" -f3");
```

not

```
# run the command named test, with its first argument '=' and its second argument
# taken from the results of invoking saltstack.
test = $(echo salt -t70 $server cmd.run "cat /etc/shadow | grep $user |cut -d\":\" -f3");
```

Comment: I actually had to remove the echo and leave as test=$(salt -t70 $server cmd.run "cat /etc/shadow | grep $user |cut -d\":\" -f3"); but it worked when doing it. Thanks

Comment: Yes -- I assumed that you intentionally had the `echo` in there to test variable capture without actually running salt.